# Problems connecting from laptop to MariaDB running on Debian 7.9 server

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I've just set up my very first Debian 7.9 server. I also installed a regular LAMP stack with MariaDB. The database is working, I've already created another user.

The problem comes up when i try to connect to my server's MariaDB from my laptop (ubuntu 14.04). I installed `mariadb-client` on my laptop and tried to connect via:

```
mysql -u myusername -p myserversadress
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on ... (111)

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u myusername -p -h myserversadress
```

The "host" was assumed to be `localhost`, and they command, if it could connect, would look for database `myserversadress`.